# When I log in after booting, the screen appears like this for a moment and then disappear

Tags: boot

[image]

When I log in after booting, the screen appears like this for a moment and then disappears. What should I do?

Comment: What have you done? What changes have you made to your system since it last worked? Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: web2py appears on the first line above, spewing an error; maybe you should consider checking the installation and/or configuration of it. hit `ESC` when the "BIOS" texts appear at boot, the grub menu should appear and allow to get into the Recovery console. What to do there depends on the content of e.g. `dmesg | less` and the other files in `/var/log/`...